# Why is my search on 2 fields in Lucene (zend) failing?

Tags: zend-framework, search, lucene, zend-search-lucene

So, I have two fields I am indexing:

```
| NAME | TYPE |
-------------------------------------
|Texas Steak | Restaurant |
|Bone Digs Restaurant | Restaurant |
|Rain Sushi | Restaurant |
|Brazil Steakhouse | Restaurant |
|Alfredos | Restaurant |
|Mediterranean Corner | Restaurant |
|Korean Taqueria | Restaurant |
|Orlando Cantina | Restaurant |
|Boomer Bar and Grill | Restaurant |
|Top Spice | Restaurant |
|Tamarind | Restaurant |
```

I am indexing in the following fashion:

```
Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_TextNum_CaseInsensitive()); 
//let lucene search for numbers as well as words
try {
$index = Zend_Search_Lucene::create('data/');
} catch(Zend_Search_Lucene_Exception $e){
echo "Unable {$e->getMessage()}";
}

$mdlPage = new Application_Model_DbTable_Business();
$currentPages = $mdlPage->fetchAll();
if($currentPages->count() >= 0) {
  foreach ($currentPages as $p) {
    $doc = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Document();
    $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text('business_name', $p->business_name));
    $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text('primary_category',$p->primary_category));
        $index->addDocument($doc);
    }
   }
   $index->commit();
   $index->optimize();
   $this->view->indexSize = $index->numDocs();
```

Now, I am querying the index in the following fashion:

```
$query = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_MultiTerm();

$query->addTerm(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($keyword,'business_name'),null);

$query->addTerm(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($keyword,'primary_category'),null);
echo $query;
try {
$results = $index->find($query);
}
catch (Zend_Search_Lucene_Exception $e) {
echo "Unable {$e->getMessage()}";
}
```

Here is the odd thing. If I query for 'thai' or any word that is in field business_name I get results. But once I query for 'restaurant' my screen does not resolve but to a white screen. If I change my code to this:

```
$query = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_MultiTerm();

//$query->addTerm(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($keyword,'business_name'),null);

$query->addTerm(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($keyword,'primary_category'),null);
```

Then I do get results. I don't get what Lucene does not like. Is it my data? Is it how I am creating my query? Or is it how I am creating my index?

Comment: you should reaaaally edit the post or somebody else and place the code as CODE